# Zxing library for android

Tags: java, android, zxing

I created a search app and I want to add a barcodescanner, so the search data can be provided by the code, I've read that there is an open library for this "zxing".It always offer us to create an intent so it will manage the situation where barcodescanner is not installed, does anyone knows if it works with other scanners like QR droid for exmple?

I think that a user don't want to change the scanner app that he/she prefers.do zxings intents work well with other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That doesn't really make sense. ZXing can't point you at something else if it's not installed. Your app could try to figure out if another scanner is installed and use that. Or you could bundle the core of ZXing (not the app) with your own UI.

Answer (score 2):

QR Droid **does** support Zxing's intent

```
com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN
```

Besides its own

```
la.droid.qr.scan
```

( http://qrdroid.com/android-developers/#2 )

If your app uses this intent, the user will be able to use either Zxing or QR Droid, the one he has.

If he has both, he'll get a prompt to choose what to choose. Just be sure to catch the case when the user doesn't have either one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several ways to use the ZXing library. One of the ways of using it with intents is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

That piece of code allows you to call the scanner and, if you happen to have another scanner app installed that also uses the zxing library, Android will offer you the possibility to choose which scanner you desire to use (with the possibility of selecting that option permanently). This is obviously because there are intent filters with the same name available in the device, so the user may choose.

To be able to use the ZXing library in this way check this site which explains very well how to integrate ZXing to your app: http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Go through my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521339/zxing-integration-camera-error/9543348#9543348). You can just do it using an intent. And if Zxing app is not installed, you get an exception, so catching that, you can redirect to android market to install that app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am fairly positive other QR readers are intent receivers for the zxing intent. I know Google goggles does. It would be fairly easy to test.